# PDFbox how to enable all fields in pdf form

Tags: pdf, pdfbox, xfa

I have a PDFForm created in Livecycle Designer. I would like import it, fill up some fields and write also like a new pdf form with enabled field. At this moment I can just fill up the fields but after export there are disabled. I also get an information: you cannot use the extended faction of pdf... How to save file with this extended pdf functions.

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("form.pdf");
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("test.pdf");

        PDDocument document  = PDDocument.loadNonSeq(in,null); 
        document.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(false);       

        Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<String, String>();
        values.put("imiePracownika", "Grzegorz K.");

        setFields(document, values);

        PDAcroForm form = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
        Document documentXML = form.getXFA().getDocument();   

        NodeList dataElements = documentXML.getElementsByTagName("xfa:data");
        if (dataElements != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataElements.getLength(); i++) {
                setXFAFields(dataElements.item(i), values);
            }
        }

        RandomAccessBuffer r = new RandomAccessBuffer();
        COSStream cosout = new COSStream(r);
        TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(new DOMSource(documentXML), new StreamResult(cosout.createUnfilteredStream()));

        form.setXFA(new PDXFA(cosout));

        document.save(out);
        document.close();


private void setFields(PDField field, Map<String, String> values) throws IOException {
    List<COSObjectable> kids = field.getKids();
    if (kids != null) {
        for (COSObjectable pdfObj : kids) {
            if (pdfObj instanceof PDField) {
                setFields((PDField) pdfObj, values);
            }
        }
    } else {
        // remove the [0] from the name to match values in our map
        String partialName = field.getPartialName().replaceAll("\\[\\d\\]", "");
        if (!(field instanceof PDSignatureField) && values.containsKey(partialName)) {
            field.setValue(values.get(partialName));
        }
    }
}


public void setFields(PDDocument pdfDocument, Map<String, String> values) throws IOException {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<PDField> fields = pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm().getFields();
    for (PDField pdField : fields) {
        setFields(pdField, values);
    }
}  


public void setXFAFields(Node pNode, Map<String, String> values) throws IOException {
    if (values.containsKey(pNode.getNodeName())) {
        pNode.setTextContent(values.get(pNode.getNodeName()));
    } else {
        NodeList childNodes = pNode.getChildNodes();
        if (childNodes != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < childNodes.getLength(); i++) {
                setXFAFields(childNodes.item(i), values);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you provide your PDF and some more information. You tagged your question as XFA - so I assume your PDF contain XFA fields. Since XFA is deprecated don't use XFA. If you use acroforms you will be able to fill out all the form fields I would guess...

Comment: I change this pdf, now I do not user XFA and it is better. I'm able to fill all fields. But when I save document all form fields are close. I do not know why. It looks like operadion create new closed document. So i result I do not have a pdf insted pdf form: